# Nodejs server - performance improvements by making loop iterations asynchronous

Tags: javascript, node.js

Consider the following server side nodejs code. Assume the code inside loop is atomic (code should be executed once) and no dependency between iterations...

```
for (var i=0; i<aVeryLargeValue; i++){
    //do atomic complex calculations
}
```

Is there a way to improve server performance by dividing the loop into parts so that iterations are executed asynchronously?

Comment: Making things asynchronous does not improve the speed of the calculation.  What is can do (if done properly) is allow other things to also run during the long running calculations.  In node, you could run a child process to work on the calculations, notifying the main process when the results were done.

Comment: My mistake. Actualy I want to improve server performance.

Comment: @jfriend00 is right - as NodeJS is single-threaded, you wont gain any performance boost by splitting this up as every loop still needs to be performed within the same thread. Put large calculations into a child process - thats the only way.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem seems to be that `aVeryLargeValue` is causing the server to take too long processing this loop and therefore holding up other requests.

Process this with the `async` module.  You can use the `whilst` function to break the loop into parts.

```
var async = require('async');

var aVeryLargeValue=99999;
var i=0;
async.whilst(
  function() { return i < aVeryLargeValue; },
  function(callback) {
    for(x=i;x<i+1000;x++) {
      //do something
    }
    i+=1000;
    callback();
  },
  function(err) {
    if(err) throw err;
  }
);
```

If this is really CPU intensive stuff then you're better off using a child process to handle it.  The above code is mainly good for times when you have to process a large request that may take a couple seconds but you don't want to hold up the rest of your requests for those couple seconds.  If your processing is going to be more than a couple seconds then you should offload it to a child process.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can split the loop into as many parts as you want, but the summary execution time will be even worse, because of the overhead.

As far as I know there is no way to run parallel loops in JavaScript (node.js respectively).